# SQL Case Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is wrong with this syntax?

```
Declare @comparisongroup int;
...
Insert Into @universitytemp Case @comparisongroup
    When -1 Then Select * From dbo.University;
    When -2 Then Select * From dbo.University Where SubDivisionName = @group; 
    When -3 Then Select * From dbo.University Where ConferenceName = @group; 
    Else Select * From dbo.GroupUniversity Where GroupID = CONVERT(int, @group);
End;
```

This doesn't work either

```
Declare @comparisongroup int;
...
Case @comparisongroup
    When -1 Then Insert Into @universitytemp Select * From dbo.University
    When -2 Then Insert Into @universitytemp Select * From dbo.University Where SubDivisionName = @group 
    When -3 Then Insert Into @universitytemp Select * From dbo.University Where ConferenceName = @group 
    Else Insert Into @universitytemp Select * From dbo.GroupUniversity Where GroupID = CONVERT(int, @group)
End;
```

Neither does this:

```
Declare @comparisongroup int;
...
Case
    When @comparisongroup = -1 Then Insert Into @universitytemp Select * From dbo.University;
    When @comparisongroup = -2 Then Insert Into @universitytemp Select * From dbo.University Where SubDivisionName = @group
    When @comparisongroup = -3 Then Insert Into @universitytemp Select * From dbo.University Where ConferenceName = @group 
    Else Insert Into @universitytemp Select * From dbo.GroupUniversity Where GroupID = CONVERT(int, @group)
End;
```

I get errors saying `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'When', 'Else', and 'End'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `CASE` is an *expression* that returns a *value*. A single value. Not a result set.

You might try:

```
SELECT
    * --todo - explicit column list
FROM
   dbo.University u
WHERE
   @comparisongroup = -1 OR
   (@comparisongroup = -2 AND SubDivisionName = @Group) OR
   (@comparisongroup = -3 AND ConferenceName = @Group)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    * --todo - explicit column list
FROM
    dbo.GroupUniversity
WHERE GroupID = CONVERT(int, @group) AND NOT @ComparisonGroup in (-1,-2,-3);
```

I.e. not use a `CASE` expression at all. As a stylistic point, I'd also probably separate `@group` into two parameters/variables - one which has "name" in its name, and continues to be (varchar?), the other of which is *explicitly* an `int` and used solely for the `GroupID` comparison.